# How to return 0 value in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How many (sum) goals were scored by each footballer in a given tournament in ascending order.
For those footballers with 0 goals, we should return name of the footballer with value 0. Point being, footballers with 0 goals should also be part of output.

```
Footballer name | Goal  | Tournament
Messi           |    3  | La liga
Ronaldo         |    5  | UEFA
Suarez          |    2  | La liga
```

Output should be for 'La Liga' output should be:

```
Ronaldo  0
Suarez   2
Messi    3
```

Comment: can you please post the expected result and the initial script you built

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select footballer, sum(goals)
from (
   select footballer, CASE
   WHEN tournament = 'LA_LIGA' THEN goals
     else 0 
   END 
   from tableA) AS tabA
group by footballer
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the structure of your database, I think normally the score is rewarded to a team instead of individuals. Anyway, here is just the concept:

Tables:

1. Players = {playerID, name, age, gender, height, etc..}
2. Games = {gameID, playerID, score...}
3. Tournaments = {tournamentID, gameID, tournamentName...}

   ```
         select p.name, IFNULL(g.score,0), t.tournamentName 
         from players p
         left join Games g on p.playerID = g.playerID 
         left join Tournaments t on g.GameID = t.GameID 
         where t.tournamentName = 'La liga'
   ```

Solution:
My point is you may need to use **IFNULL(..)** and set the default value to 0.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
Select FootballerName, 
sum(CASE WHEN tournament = 'LA LIGA' THEN Goal  else 0 END) as Goal 
from #Matches group by FootballerName
```

want to get all goals by players in all tournament

```
Select FootballerName, sum(Goal) as Goal 
from #Matches group by FootballerName
```

want to know goals touranmentwise

```
Select FootballerName, sum(Goal) as Goal,Tournament 
from #Matches group by FootballerName,Tournament
```

Comment: it works but what if we require for all the matches.

Comment: for all matches just remove case statement... directly write sum(goal)

Comment: pls elaborate your query

Comment: If I needed to know goals by all individuals in all tournament. Your answer is only one tournament through its was the primary question.

Comment: want to know goals tournament wise?

Comment: I have already found the query to find one, if you have a different answer, please share always ready to explore other options too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145419/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-ravi).

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have 3 tables (players, tournaments, and goals) you'll need to create 3 sets using subselects and join them together. You need the cross-product of all tournaments and all footballers.

```
SELECT footballer_name, tournament FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT footballer_name FROM your_table) AS players
  JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT tournament FROM your_table) AS tournaments
```

The above should get you one record per unique pairing of footballer and tournament. See if you can get this working in your database and then finish it off with a final join for scores

Comment: no need for 3 tables, we can use pivot to get the desired result with provided table itself.

Comment: the subject line report for SQL and not mysql, Pivot too can be acheived differently in mysql check out an example [http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78]

Comment: If you could show us the tables and the result using the above suggested. If you can elaborate on the Join syntax you are using.

Comment: Please check I have answered for both SQL and MySql Version.

Comment: If I try to use as suggested by you, I am getting this error. Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Thanks for the double-check. I had an extra parenthesis. My edited version should satisfy the requirement now as every subselect (wrapped in parentheses) has an alias.

Comment: The error which I shared, is when I executed the query, I did correct the typo. Sorry I am not sure if you did tried to execute the statement before posting your answer. Please use the table script shared by me and try to execute the answer you suggested you will not get the required result.

Answer (score -1):

[Source Of Information:](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) Pivot query help us to generate an interactive table that quickly combines and compares large amounts of data. We can rotate its rows and columns to see different summaries of the source data, and we can display the details for areas of interest at a glance. It also help us to generate Multidimensional reporting.

**Create Table script**

```
Create table Matches(FootballerName varchar(100),Goal int ,Tournament varchar(100))
```

**Sql Server Insert Records script**

```
insert into Matches(FootballerName,Goal,Tournament)
select 'Messi ', 3 ,'La liga' union
select 'Ronaldo ', 5 ,'UEFA' union
select 'Surez ', 2 ,'La liga'
```

**MySql Server script**

```
   Create table Matches(FootballerName varchar(100),Goal int ,Tournament varchar(100));
insert into Matches(FootballerName,Goal,Tournament)
select 'Messi ', 3 ,'La liga' union
select 'Ronaldo ', 5 ,'UEFA' union
select 'Surez ', 2 ,'La liga';
```

**MYSQL Version**

```
Select FootBallerName,
Sum(CASE WHEN Tournament= 'La liga' THEN goal ELSE 0 END) AS 'La liga',
Sum(CASE WHEN Tournament= 'UEFA' THEN goal ELSE 0 END) AS 'UEFA'from Matches 
group by FootBallerName order by FootBallerName;
```

**SQL Server Query using Pivot --- for Only [La liga]**

```
SELECT FootballerName,isnull([La liga],0) as'La liga'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        FootballerName  ,isnull(goal,0) as'goal', 
        Tournament
    FROM Matches
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(goal)
    FOR Tournament IN ([La liga],[UEFA])
)AS pvt order by [La liga]
```

**SQL Server Query using Pivot ---  Only [La liga] and [UEFA]**

```
SELECT FootballerName,isnull([La liga],0) as'La liga',isnull([UEFA],0) as'UEFA'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        FootballerName  ,isnull(goal,0) as'goal', 
        Tournament
    FROM Matches
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(goal)
    FOR Tournament IN ([La liga],[UEFA])
)AS pvt order by [La liga],[UEFA]
```

You can read more [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe the PIVOT statement is in MySQL, which is what this post was tagged under.

Comment: @alvaz : Pivot too can be acheived differently in mysql check out an example [http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78]

Comment: @alvaz if can please check my answer.